# How to host a SignalR application with GoDaddy?

Tags: signalr, web-hosting

I've written a small demo application using the ASP.net SignalR library.  It works fine when run locally, but when I deploy it to my server hosted by GoDaddy, it gives the following error: `GET http://xxxxxxx.com/techdemo/signalr/hubs 404 (Not Found)`

I did a Google search and was only able to find this one article: https://blog.adamzolo.com/hosting-signalr-godaddy-full-trust/.  Unfortunately, the advice there didn't fix my problem.

I know from the documentation that signalr/hubs is a Javascript file generated by SignalR.  Somehow, it doesn't get loaded when the site is hosted by GoDaddy.  I need to get this working, so what do I do to make it work?

Comment: I contacted their support team.  The person I spoke to said he had never heard of SignalR.  These sort of libraries should be deployed in the bin directory, AFAIK.  He said that I may need to pay for a "virtual private server" to make it work.